# helper method is called recursively

Tags: lightning-aura-components, helper

I'm trying to fetch the list of opportunities related to the account(called as Student in my case) selected(from dropdown list).

I have 2 buttons with different aura:ids what I want is, when I click on the button one I wish to call apex method one(getOpportunities) and save the response to aura:attribute one(lstOpportunities) similarly when I click on button two I wish to call apex method two(getOpportunities1) and save the response in aura:attribute two(lstOpportunities1). In the code below, it's calling the helper method recursively infinite times.

However, if I uncomment the if else statements then it's not calling the setCallback code block.
My helper method is

```
helperGetOpportunities : function(component,event){
    var selectedStudentId;
    var getLstOpportunities;
    //if(event.getSource().getLocalId() === 'showstudentsfromsearchbypicklist'){ //aura:Id of student's select option
        console.log('1111');
        selectedStudentId = component.get('v.selectedStudentId');
        getLstOpportunities = component.get('c.getOpportunities');
    //}
    //else{
      //  selectedStudentId = component.get('v.selectedStudentId1');
      //  getLstOpportunities = component.get('c.getOpportunities1');
    //}
    console.log('Id is : '+selectedStudentId);
    getLstOpportunities.setParams({
        studentId : selectedStudentId
    });        
    getLstOpportunities.setCallback(this , function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        console.log('Here i am 1');
        if(state === 'SUCCESS'){
            console.log('Here i am 2');
            //if(event.getSource().getLocalId() === 'showstudentsfromsearchbypicklist'){ //aura:Id of student's select option
                console.log('response is : '+response.getReturnValue());
                component.set("v.lstOpportunities",response.getReturnValue());
           // }
           // else{
                //component.set("v.lstOpportunities1",response.getReturnValue());
            //}

        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(getLstOpportunities);
}
```

The apex methods getOpportunities and getOpportunities1 are only returning the list of opportunities related to given student id.
Can anyone help me in finding the problem with this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your helper is getting called recursively, it means you have a method name conflict between the client and server, which, in this case, appears to be getOpportunities. You should probably have a warning on the browser's console log to this effect. Always make sure that there are not client-side and controller-side AuraEnabled methods with the same name.